# Add custom header to all Swagger responses in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

We are having WebApi server with Swagger for documenting the endpoints. We want to add Content-Security-Policy and X-Frame-Options headers. We wanted to achieve this by intercepting the calls and adding the custom headers, however we are unable to find a way to do so. We are using Swashbuckle Swagger for WebApi NuGet package with 5.0.4 version.

Is there a way to intercept Swagger responses or any way for adding custom header to the responses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to add the headers to all responses one option would be to add a `DelegatingHandler` that could add the headers in by overriding the `SendAsync` method. So you would create a class that inherits from `DelegatingHandler` and then override `SendAsync`. e.g.:

```
public class AddCustomHeadersResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

         response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "yourSecurityValue");

         response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "yourFrameOptions");

         return response;
    }
}
```

Then add an instance of the class to your configuration in `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new AddCustomHeadersResponseHandler());
```

Comment: Works like a charm, just few tweaks have to be added to filter only the swagger calls, but this totally will work for my case. Thank you very much!